# Access array element in javascript by method not by indexer

Tags: javascript

Access an element of array by using indexer is very simple.

```
a = [1,2,3]
> a[1] = 1
```

But my question is how to do that with method? I'm looking for a method looks like this:

```
> a.get(1) = 1
```

I've been searching for awhile but it seems JavaScript doesn't support that method. Am I missing anything? Or does any library support that?

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you trying to be unnecessarily complicated?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Why are you trying to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Use a.splice(index, 0, item);

Comment: Actually, I am doing a job that I have to define an object with key is method, and value is parametor like that: `{
    'find': 'meta[property="al:ios:url"',
    'attr': 'content',
    'split': 'id=',
}`. After splitting, I want to pick up a element in array. That why I need an method.

Comment: Do you mean something like `a.set(1, 1);`? You can't put a method call of the left side of an assignment statement.

Comment: @LittleZero your explanation does not actually explain why you need that.

Comment: @zerkms I receive a JSON from server, and that JSON define css selectors. Instead of using jQuery with simple expression:  `$(meta[property="al:ios:url").attr('content').split('id=')[1]`, I have to read the JSON and if the keys are methods, then I can use `jQuery['find']('meta[property="al:ios:url"')['attr']('content')['split']('id=')`. And that is, I am getting stuck in the last indexer.

Comment: so you can not use [0] ?

Comment: @cale_b Thank for sharing, Maybe I chose wrong way from start.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript Arrays are simple sequential data structures. While there are many methods for enumeration, there is no .get() method.

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to avoid accessing by index, you could always use **[`.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values)** and iterate over each element in the array. However, note that the following will only work in Edge and Safari 9+:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var iterator = a.values();

for (let e of iterator) {
  console.log(e);
}

// 1
// 2
// 3
```

Comment: Thanks, but It seems useless to me when it doesn't work in Chrome

Comment: The lack of support is probably because Chrome can simply access by index with `a[i]`, which is much faster and easier to write :P